# how to do a continue in an xslt for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

How to do a **continue** in an xslt `for-each` (not exiting the `for-each`, but rather **continue** the `for-each`?

Like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="asd">

    <xsl:if test="$test1">
        <!--some stuff-->
        <xsl:if test="$test1A">
            <!--CONTINUE()-->
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$test2">
        <!--some stuff-->
        <!--CONTINUE()-->
    </xsl:if>

    <!--main stuff-->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, seems you want possibly execute both codes according to a condition. In fact you want to continue from the first `if` only if `$test1A` is true.

In this case `xsl:choose` does not help you. You have to work with pure logic and emulate the wanted behavior:

```
<xsl:for-each select="asd">
    <xsl:if test="$test1">
        <!--some stuff-->
        <xsl:if test="$test1A">
            <!--CONTINUE()-->
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$test2 and not($test1A)">
        <!--some stuff-->
        <!--CONTINUE()-->
    </xsl:if>
    <!--main stuff-->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Use conditions as above, you will execute the second `if` *only if* the nested `if` in the first branch is false.

Answer (score 1):

Think you need xml:choose and xml:when. [xsl:choose](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-choose) element selects **one** among a number of possible alternatives. So when expression is evaluate to true, it execute that block and then  goes to the next loop.

Comment: If the OP's sample input correctly reflects its problem, `xsl:choose` will not help him at all. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no construct analogous to a `continue` in XSL. You will have to restructure your code flow to achieve the same effect.

I would suggest breaking up the entirety of the loop body into smaller chunks in order to minimize the number of compound if's.

*Edit:*

Here's what it looks like when you use full compound ifs:

```
<xsl:for-each select="asd">
    <xsl:if test="$test1">
        <!--some stuff (1)-->
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($test1 and $test1A)">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$test2">
                <!--some stuff (2)-->            
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!--main stuff (3)-->    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Every time you need a `continue` you need to wrap all following code in a guard.

The code is harder to read as a single statement and if there is any substantial amount of code inside those if's you would do well to break them out into their own templates and call out to them.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. See my answer.